# Need to somehow change the formatting of a column of data from text to date

Tags: python, excel

I've been handed a few sheets of data that I need to compare and contrast for a Uni project.

I have 2 sheets where the date/time format is `01/08/2020 00:01`. Which is perfect for what I need to do. The third sheet has the date formatted (for some inexplicable reason) as `2020-08-01T00:01:00.0000000`.

It's in normal text instead of date format, and there's 1000s of rows, and they don't follow the same increments, so I can't just start at the top and drag down.  Obviously, I can't do it manually.  I'm wondering if there's some Python code that I could use that recognises the year, data and day, reformat them according, replace the T with a space, and get rid of the 7 zeros at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a formula to extract the dates you need. Assuming your strings start in cell A1, you can use this formula:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))
```